# Go back in character search in vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a shortcut to go back when doing a "go-to character" search in vim? Like if I press `f , ; ;` to find the third comma, but accidently press one more `;` then necessary, is there a quick way to back one comma without doing `F ,`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Comma is actually bound to "Repeat latest f, t, F or T in opposite direction".

Comment: It is in vogue to set the leader to comma, `let mapleader = ","`. If the `,` command is not working correctly look in your `.vimrc` file to see if this is the case.